# download two paired files in loop function before proceeding

Tags: bash, loops

I have a loop that first downloads a file using a url link then processes it with `samtools`. For each file in `input.txt` there is one *.cram and one *.crai file which have the same name except the ending. Both these files need to be downloaded before `samtools` can be run. I wonder how to download both the *.cram and one *.crai using `mapfile` before proceeding to the `samtools` step.

test.txt

```
gs://hmf-cram-1231313-drup01010104/file1_dedup.realigned.cram 
gs://hmf-cram-1231313-drup01010104/file1_dedup.realigned.crai
gs://hmf-cram-1234235353-drup01242424/file1_dedup.realigned.cram 
gs://hmf-cram-1234235353-drup01242424/file1_dedup.realigned.crai
```

script

```
#!/bin/bash
mapfile -s 1 -t files < test.txt 
echo "${files[@]}"
for FILE in ${files[@]}; do
        gsutil -u absolute-bison-xxxx cp $FILE gs://bucket_1
        samtools view -@5  -O bam -f 4 ${FILE##*/}.cram > /home/user/${FILE##*/}.unmapped.bam
        rm *.cram
        rm *.crai;
done
```

Comment: Note that without quotes, `for FILE in ${files[@]}` acts *exactly* like `for FILE in ${files[*]}`. You don't want those bugs; use `for FILE in "${files[@]}"` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`xargs` may help you better here.
First point is your input `test.txt` has odd lines with a trailing space, so I opted to deal with this:

```sh
xargs -l1 -a test.txt sh -c ';
basefile="${1##*/}";
basefile="${basefile%.*}";
if \
  gsutil -u absolute-bison-xxxx cp "$1" gs://bucket_1 \
  && samtools view -@5  -O bam -f 4 "$basefile.cram" \
  >"/home/user/$basefile.unmapped.bam";
then
  rm -- "./$basefile.cra"[im];
fi;
' _
```

Here the shell script run for each argument provided by `xargs`:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

# Remove leading path
basefile="${1##*/}"

# Remove last trailing dot extension
basefile="${basefile%.*}"

# Do the cloud stuffs
if \
  gsutil -u absolute-bison-xxxx cp "$1" gs://bucket_1 \
  && samtools view -@5  -O bam -f 4 "$basefile.cram" \
    >"/home/user/$basefile.unmapped.bam"
then
  # Cleanup .cran and .crai files
  rm -- "./$basefile.cra"[im]
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

I would pass test.txt to the script when you invoke it:

```
./script < test.txt
```

Then process a record at a time.  In this case it appears to be two lines:

```
while read cram && read crai
do
   process "$cram" "$crai"
done
```

I have not used mapfile, gsutil and samtools, btw, so I don't know who the two files come into play.  However, I would validate the assumption that the two files are a matching pair and avoid the wildcard rm:

```
process() {
   local cram=$1
   local crai=$2

   if [ "$cram" != "${crai%crai}cram" ]
   then
       echo "Pair does not match: cram=$cram, crai=$crai" 1>&2
       return
    fi

    ...

    rm -- "${cram##*/}" "${crai##*/}"
}
```

Comment: `while IFS= read -r cram && IFS= read -r crai; do ...` if we want to read the lines exactly as-is (preserving backslashes, trailing whitespace, etc).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy it's a good point, but in this case it seemed to work fine as is.

Comment: To be sure; I'm just uneasy assuming that the data format given in the OP's examples are all they'll ever need to process. If they ever _do_ get a filename with a backslash in it, or get run in a context where `IFS` contains characters that their filenames could start or end with, letting `read` munge the name is probably not desired. Safer to default to leaving the data as it's written in the input file, instead of defaulting to letting the shell corrupt it.

Comment: BTW, you can put a `< test.txt` after your `done`; no reason to change how the script is started.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy yes, I know, but given file name it seemed variable.

Comment: Sure; that was suggested along the lines of making it clear to the OP that they could continue to provide the name from within the script, since that's what their original code does.

Answer (score 0):

> I wonder how to download both the *.cram and one *.crai using mapfile before proceeding to the samtools step.

Using `mapfile` but inside a `while` loop.

```
while mapfile -n2 -t cram_crai && ((${#cram_crai[@]} == 2)); do
  echo "${cram_crai[@]}"
  # The rest of your script here.
done < test.txt
```

Just in case you want to process more lines at a time just increase the value of `2`'s.

First element in the array is `0` which is `*.cram`

```
"${cram_crai[0]}"
```

Second element is `1` which is `*.crai`

```
"${cram_crai[1]}"
```

Parameter Expansion also applies with array expansion.

```
"${cram_crai[@]##*/}"
```